# Change Android Emulator resolution When using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using the standard Android emulator that comes with Visual Studio 2019 with a Xamarin project but the resolution is ridiculously low as you can see:

[image]

I'm trying to build a simple login screen and my screen has a small logo, the username and password field and a reset password link and the screen is pretty much full. I should have a tonne of space but it's not the case.

Is there anyway to increase this as I was on my own phone for example (Samsung S8+)?

I found a couple of article mentioning this should be done when creating the virtual image, but there is no mention of what properties should be set to?

Thanks.

**Update-1**

I've just added a few properties I noticed were missing from the emulator property list but it made no difference:

- hw.lcd.density : 560
- hw.lcd.height  : 2560
- hw.lcd.width   : 1440
- hw.ramSize     : 1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are trying to edit the properties on an existing image, which I don't know if it would work. Have you tried creating a new image?

In the android device manager (tools > Android > Android Device Manager), click on new to create a new image. Set the base device to generic Phone Xh-DPI 4.7". This populates the fields density/height/width with 320/720/1280. Adjust as needed and hit create. Once created, set this as your deploy target.

Comment: I updated my answer as this is what I tried but it didn't work so I ended up re-creating an image alright and just ensure I picked a higher resolution device which is a lot more realistic. Thanks.